# Add variable into url curl command

Tags: macos, curl

I want to add a variable into my curl POST command. My level is very low...

I try something, but doesn't work...

```
# Commande pour récupérer l'UDID

udid=$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep -i "UUID" | awk 'NR==1{print $3}')
echo "$udid"
url="https://xxxxxxx.jamfcloud.com/api/devices/"$udid"/refresh"
echo "$url"


# Commande pour ajout groupe API

function refresh(){
    curl --location --request POST "'"$url"'" \
--header 'Authorization: Basic ********************************=' \
--header 'Cookie: hash=***********************'
}

refresh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wrap the URL in single quotes in the `curl` command. In other words instead of

```
curl --location --request POST "'"$url"'"
```

do

```
curl --location --request POST "$url"
```

Related to that is this line:

```
url="https://xxxxxxx.jamfcloud.com/api/devices/"$udid"/refresh"
```

should simply be

```
url="https://xxxxxxx.jamfcloud.com/api/devices/$udid/refresh"
```

Comment: I'd also recommend removing the inner double-quotes in the `url=` line (the ones around `$udid`). They actually un-double-quote the variable, which doesn't make any difference in this particular context but would in most others. In general, variable references (like `$udid` or `$url`) should be inside double-quotes (no single-quotes, and only a single layer of double-quotes).

Comment: @GordonDavisson makes a good point. In general, in any POSIX shell you should always double-quote the expansion of any variable. Even if you are confident the value does not contain any shell meta characters. Even better is to use a sane, modern, shell like Fish or Elvish which don't have those land mines ready to maim you.